# Split node padding when using `align` in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, nodes

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]{
    x y%
    \nodepart{two}{%
      \tikz \node[draw, rectangle] {bubble \\ gum};%
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{2em}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[align=center, rectangle split part align={center, left}, draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]{
    x y%
    \nodepart{two}{%
      \tikz \node[draw, rectangle] {bubble \\ gum};%
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{2em}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[align=left,draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]{
    x y%
    \nodepart{two}{%
      \tikz \node[draw, rectangle] {bubble \\ gum};%
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following:

[image: Node alignment problem]

In the first example, the inner node is correctly nested in the center of the  outer one. However, line breaks in the inner node content are ignored.

Adding `align=center` or `align=left` to the options of the outer node results in the line breaks being respected, but the inner node is not centered any more. I don't understand why this is happening.

How can I get the desired behaviour: line breaks are displayed and the inner node is centered within the outer one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle split part align={center, left}, draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]{
    x y%
    \nodepart{two}{%
      \tikz \node[align=center, draw, rectangle] {bubble \\ gum};%
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{2em}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]{
    x y%
    \nodepart{two}{%
      \tikz \node[align=left,draw, rectangle] {bubble \\ gum};%
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]